# What is better ? Using a double backward slash ('\\') as file seperator or Files.seperator to remove O.S. Dependency while working with files in java

Tags: java, filesystems

So i have made an application which performs some reading/writing to files. I want to make the Path Traversal as independent of O.S.

Different operating systems use different characters as file separators. For example, Microsoft Windows systems use `"\"`, while UNIX systems use `"/"`. When applications have to run on different platforms, the use of hardcoded file separators can lead to incorrect execution of application logic.

So i came up with using a double backward slash `'\\'`. But now i came to that i can use

```
 public static final String FILE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("file.separator");
 public static final String PATH_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("path.separator");
```

reference here http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=38.

Am i wrong ? What is the correct way ?

Comment: Windows understands / but Unix-like systems don't understand \\, so if at all you should use / not \\.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way is to use `File.separator` for the separator between path names and `File.pathSeparator` for the separator between paths. Those are identical to the `"file.separator"` and `"path.separator"` properties.

`System.getProperty("file.separator")` would return "/" on UNIX and "\" on Windows.

`System.getProperty("path.separator")` would return ":" on UNIX and ";" on Windows.

You may check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html.

Comment: My question is wheter using '\\' or using File.seperator are same or there is a difference. If there is a difference what is a better way ?

Comment: Using File.separator is better since it resolves to the right character depending on the OS instead of just hardcoding the separator.

Answer (score 2):

In java depending on which system your programm is executed on, the separator may be different.
For example, on Linux Filesystem it is the '/' separator.
On Windows Filesystem it is the '\' separator.

So if you use the File.separator you will be sure the right separator will be used and no problem will occur this way.