# I want to separate the the file path which has worker/src/main/java/Text.java

Tags: java

I want to separate the file path using java
Source File path: worker/src/main/java/Text.java

**Expected Output :** `worker/src/main/java`

For that I tried below code

```
String filePath = "worker/src/main/java/Text.java"

String path = new file(filePath).getParent();
```

**Actual output :** `worker\src\main\java`

But I want the output "worker/src/main/java" Like this
and want to print only "src" can you please suggest me how can I get those outputs?

Thanks
Vaasu

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want the file path like that? "\" is valid in windows file paths.

Comment: A dangerous and not recommended way to do this is a substring (It will fail on Linux filesystems): `path = filePath.substring(0,filePath.lastIndexOf("/"));`

Comment: Possible duplicate [What is better ? Using a double backward slash ('\\') as file seperator or Files.seperator to remove O.S. Dependency while working with files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137446/what-is-better-using-a-double-backward-slash-as-file-seperator-or-files)

Comment: Thanks, I can able to get the out put that I want. how can I print only "src". can you please suggest me.

Comment: You can use substrings multiple times to get a specific part of the path.